# Android Studio Import Project Gradle Build Fail

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, build.gradle, android-virtual-device

[Gradle Build Issuse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYSPK.png)

I been trying to build the app but the main problem I am having is the builds cradle version. I am still new to the world of coding and would like to be able to solve this problem. I am currently using the Murach Android Programming as my guide. I have tried using the recommendations android studio has given but it stills fails. Please help

Comment: To my mind,  the Build Issue clearly shows, what's the problem here. As it says "builds using gradle versions older than 2.6 was removed". It looks like this project is ancient. You either can try to upgrade the gradle build or start a new android project and copy the old code base.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your gradle wrapper to 2.6 and re-import the project(tap the error text in console area).

Answer (score 0):

Click the blue link in the console that says

> "Upgrade gradle wrapper to 2.6 version and re-import the project"

This is the simplest solution as it seems your gradle version is outdated.